# Why does the while loop never stop looping?

Tags: python, while-loop

Below is the snippet of my code. Let's assume that the output of `play_again()` inside the while loop returns False. Then, why does my while loop keep on looping? Is there is some concept I'm unaware of?

```
game_list = ['0','1','2']

while True:

    position = myfunc()
    
    replacement(game_list,position)
    
    play_again()

print(game_list)
```

Comment: while true never stops unless you tell it to break.

Comment: "*while loop returns False*" but you don't store the return value anywhere or update the while loop condition. Your while loop is permanently stuck at `while True`.

Comment: True but i don't want it to break till i tell it so using play_again!

Comment: It does not matter what `play_again` returns, as this is never evaluated. `while True` will indeed loop endlessly.

Comment: "*but i don't want it to break till i tell it so* If the output of `play_again` is False, then why don't you want to `break`?

Comment: @gino I was answering as to why I cannot give break command!!

Comment: If an answer worked for you, you should accept it to make other users sure that it is a working answer. 
If it didn't work you should edit your question to make others understanding what is wrong with their code.
Welcome to Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for helping me understand this concept. All respective answers worked for me though my purpose was just to understand the concept behind my wrongdoing.I don't have enough reputation to upvode your answer else I would have already done it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is b/c the `while True` does not end unless you use the keyword `break` wich breaks outside the loop and continues the code.
the `while True` never ends

the while loop

```
while (condition):
    #code
```

never ends until the condition is `False`, witch would never be true for the `True` condition.

do your code should be:

```
game_list = ['0','1','2']

while True:

    position = myfunc()

    replacement(game_list,position)

    if not play_again():
         break
print(game_list)
```

or you could do:

```
game_list = ['0','1','2']

while play_again():

    position = myfunc()

    replacement(game_list,position)

print(game_list)
```

Comment: James- Hi thanks for answer. Your answers first line-this is b/c the while True....... But what if we return False ??? it should also cause while loop to break

Comment: no, b/c the while loop is going to continue if the condition is true, true is always true so it doesn't, if you return something it doesn't go into the condition.

Comment: I would suggest the OP to use your second snippet of code and never the first. Anyway nice explaination, +1

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
while (play_again()):
    position = myfunc()
    replacement(game_list,position)
```

---

You should know that in Python a `while` loop (like in every other programming language) takes a single "argument", that is a `condition` of type `bool`:

```
while (i > 3): # i>3 is a boolean condition
    ...
```

In fact this is equivalent to

```
while (True): # the loop continues until condition is False, so in this case it will never stop
    if (i > 3):
        break
```

In Python `break` is a keyword that makes you exit the loop.

---

Then, as you probably understood, this code is equivalent to the first snippet in this answer:

```
while (True):
    position = myfunc()
    replacement(game_list,position)
    if (not play_again()):
        break
```

Comment: Yeah but returning `False` inside `while True` should also end `while loop`?

Comment: No. If you are returning without assignment, the value (in this case False) simply got lost.

Imagine if you call inside a while loop a function that returns True and one that returns False. How could the compiler know if it has to continue or to break the loop?

Comment: GOt it . Thaanks :)

Answer (score 0):

while True will run until you decide to break.

```
game_list = ['0','1','2']
while True:

    position = myfunc()
    
    replacement(game_list,position)
    
    play_again = input("do you want to play again?")
    if play_again == 'y':

        play_again()
    else:
        break

print(game_list)
```